# More accurate scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

See this page:
http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html

Try and scroll to 10,20 or 30% position using the mouse-wheel. It is not possible. It seems to jump to 33%, 66% and 100% as if they are anchors. That makes sense on a large page if you want to scroll quickly through the page.

But the page I am using it for I need more control, I need it to be able to easily scroll to specific points. Is that possible to do that where I can use the mousewheel to scroll more specifically to say 8,22,47%. Of course, it might not be possible to scroll to those exact points but it should be easy enough to scroll and slightly adjust with the mouse-wheel to get to that point you want.

Is that basically what smooth scroll is and if so do I just turn it off or do i need a jquery script to able to do this on my website or can you adjust your current script to change the anchors so instead of jumping 10% it only jumps 2% which would likely give more control.

On this particular page there wouldn't be a ton of scrolling needed but you do want to be able to stop it at specific points otherwise one tile is half cut off and then you have to use your mouse on the scrollbar to move it to a specific point where its not cut off.

Comment: The "anchors" are defined by your settings, probably windows. Go look in `Control Panel > Mouse` then probably `Scrolling` or `Mouse wheel`. There's a setting to scroll so many lines at a time. Now if you want to scroll to specific parts of the page see [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

Comment: But is there a way to override them for a smoother scrolling. For example trello seem to have smoother scrolling on their board

Comment: I'm not sure I understand entirely what you mean. You have a mouse whose wheel clicks into each position, right? Then it will scroll in chunks. I'm not sure how Trello behaves for you, could you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not really know what was the best solution at the time but the problem was that I had a view like Trello with cards and when I used the mouse scroll often it would stop with half the card cut off, the only way to see the full card was to stop the mouse wheel scroll and manual use the scrollbar to pull it to an exact position.

As it turns out there was a perfect solution. http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html

See the last solution, snap scrolling to images, I used that but snapped to the top of the card so for each mouse scroll it moves to show a new card which is the perfect solution for me and hopefully will solve other users with similar layouts.

The initial link I posted did not have this solution even though it was the same code repo, I stumbled across the solution later but I accept I probably did not explain my question very well initially